# How to pass value returned by a method of a class as a parameter for test case in PyTest?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I am trying to pass a value returned by a class method into a test method in the same class.

```
def SampleTest:

    # my dynamic value generation function
    def dynamicValue(self):
        result = 10
        return result

    # how to pass a value returned by dynamicValue method?
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('value', [1, 2, dynamicValue])
    def test_case(self, value):
        print(f'Testing for input value {value}')
        # testing functionality...
```

By dynamic value I mean some numeric value fetched from operating system during collect phase of tests execution. How to do this correctly? Above example doesn't work.

Comment: You can't do that by keeping `dymanicValue` an instance method. Move the method outside of a class and make it a function, then call the function in `parametrize` mark to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pytest [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/special.html?highlight=fixture) to pass a value as input for a test. This feature of pytest is really nice because you just need to use a decorator on your method, then you can pass the function to other tests!

Here is a complete example which passes when run with pytest:

```
import pytest


class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture
    def dynamic_value(self):
        return 10

    def test_case(self, dynamic_value):
        # This assertion only passes if dynamic_value is passed properly
        assert dynamic_value == 10
```

Comment: I need to pass a mix (list or set) of static numbers and dynamically fetched from OS values. Eg. [1,2,dynamicValue()], one value per test execution. Your solution doesn't allow to do that. Moreover fixtures are not executed during collect phase, but execution phase.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood then, my apologies. Thank you for pointing out the issue with my answer. Best of luck!